# EF Code First 5 - How to define nullable foreign key using Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, fluent

I have two table -

```
 1. Account 

 2. Users
```

In `Account` table, `DefaultExpensePartner` and `AccountOwner` are foreign key of `UserId` field of `Users` table. I have defined classes as below.

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public int? AccountOwnerId { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultExpensePartnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Users AccountOwner { get; set; }
    public virtual Users DefaultExpensePartner { get; set; }
}

public class AccountConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public AccountConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Account");

        this.HasKey(c => c.AccountId);

        this.Property(c => c.AccountId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.AccountName)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.AccountOwnerId)
            .HasColumnName("AccountOwner")
            .IsOptional();

        this.Property(c => c.DefaultExpensePartnerId)
            .HasColumnName("DefaultExpensePartner")
            .IsOptional();

        this.HasRequired(c => c.DefaultExpensePartner)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.DefaultExpensePartnerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasRequired(c => c.AccountOwner)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.AccountOwnerId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class Users
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt1 { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt2 { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}

public class UsersConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Users>
{
    public UsersConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Users");

        this.HasKey(c => c.UserId);

        this.Property(c => c.UserId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(80)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.DisplayName)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.PasswordSalt1)
            .HasMaxLength(172)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.PasswordSalt2)
            .HasMaxLength(172)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.PasswordHash)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Though I am able to establish foreign key relationship for `AccountOwner` and `DefaultExpensePartner` fields, they are defined as non-null in database which is incorrect according to my original plan. Can anyone know how to define foreign key as nullable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to specify the key-property unless you really want to, which is kinda the idea of code first :)

According to [this article by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx) it should be enough to remove the foreign key properties. Have a look at the differences between figure 1 and figure 2 in the article. (The keys will of course be generated at the database level, but do you really need them in the model?)

Comment: Of course, I need this in model because this is how's it is supposed to be in database. I am still looking for the solution. :-(

Comment: Oh I forgot to reply, I think you were right. It's not possible to add nullable foreign key and not having so also makes sense. I re-designed database structure and now everything is great.

Comment: Can some one please help me with this related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571025/how-to-correctly-set-foreign-key-constraint-in-one-to-many-relationship-in-code

Answer (score 16):

If you want to have *nullable* foreign key, why are you defining it as *required*:

```
this.HasRequired
```

?

Use `HasOptional` instead:

```
        this.HasOptional(c => c.AccountOwner)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.AccountOwnerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: I already tried using HasOptional but it doesn't change anything in the structure. I don't know whey different terminologies have used for the same functionality. It looks like they might act differently at front-end.

Comment: Can some one please help me with this related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571025/how-to-correctly-set-foreign-key-constraint-in-one-to-many-relationship-in-code