# How to correctly set foreign key constraint in one to many relationship in code first ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

So I have one document table and a ApplicationUser table. One user can upload multiple documents and a foreign key constraint has been applied accordingly using the code first approach. But the problem is, **I am able to save the document without assigning the UserID foreign key id in the Documents table**. What am I missing here? Below is my novice attempt.

**ApplicationUser Model:**

it's the standard model provided by the framework.

**Document Model:**

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

**Post Action**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Document doc, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedresume)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (uploadedresume != null && uploadedresume.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var tempdoc = new Document
                {
                    FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadedresume.FileName),
                    ContentType = uploadedresume.ContentType,
                    DocumentName = doc.DocumentName
                };
                using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(uploadedresume.InputStream))
                {
                    tempdoc.Content = reader.ReadBytes(uploadedresume.ContentLength);
                }
                _context.Documents.Add(tempdoc);
            }
            // YOU CAN CLEARLY SEE I HAVE NOT SET THE tempdoc.UserId PROPERTY WITH THE LOGGED  IN USER ID
            // WHY AM I NOT GETTING ERROR HERE CONSTRAINT ERROR??
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
    }
    catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */){
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
    }
    return View("Create");
}
```

**One to Many Migration**

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Documents",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                FileName = c.String(maxLength: 255),
                ContentType = c.String(maxLength: 100),
                Content = c.Binary(),
                DocumentName = c.String(maxLength: 255),
                UserId = c.String(maxLength: 128),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId)
        .Index(t => t.UserId);

}

public override void Down()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Documents", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
    DropIndex("dbo.Documents", new[] { "UserId" });
    DropTable("dbo.Documents");
}
}
```

**Entry in Documents table:**

[image]

**Expected Behavior**

> If I have set up FK constraint properly then I should have seen the constraint error when saving in database. It
>   should not have allowed NULL values because it is not a valid userId
>   that is there in ApplicationUserId Table.

**Or nullable foreign key is the expected behavior??**

Comment: I deleted my answer becasue this is the last time I help you. It seems that you've a great problem about how to read solution posted on SO. Anyway this is third time I encountered that with you :-)

Comment: I am really sorry if you feel this way. I am not very intelligent. I understand stuff but it takes time for me to comprehend. Anyways, I had copied your solution before you deleted, so that I can implement and understand it even more. And the problem you told about not understanding the solution posted on SO. I will try to work on that.

Comment: And thanks for your time though.

Comment: Okey, finally I understood on thing by experimentation I might be wrong. So, no matter even if foreign key is set up correctly in entity framework code first approach it will keep the FOREIGN KEY as NULLABLE ENTITY. I used to think that just because I told entity framework to make one id as foreign key, it will automatically make it Non Nullable. But that is not the case. Anyways if I really want to make the Foreign Key NonNullable, it's important for me to add "REQUIRED" data annotation.

Comment: Okey, "required" data annotation now will be caught at "ModelState.Isvalid" itself. But suppose if I forget to add that check. then my DB will now thrown an DB Constraint error too. So even if I do not put the modelstate.isvsalid property and allow the data to be saved in DB. My DB will now throw DB Constarint error.

Comment: And yes, we can use fluent api and all. But for me those are advanced concepts as of now. So from now on "I will make sure I add "Required"  annotation explicitly to the foreign keys to make it non nullable.

Comment: I always used to think that if I put any property as foreign key it will be non nullable. But I was WRONG. I need to put required attribute on top of it, in order to  make it non nullable.

Comment: @CodeNotFound: I know you won't answer anymore to my question. But can you atleast reply as "yes" or "no" to my above comments. yes: if my understanding is correct. and "no: if my understading is still wrong. Just one reply, and I wont bother you after this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can configure this in the function onModelCreating into your context file, something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Documents)
            .WithRequired(d => d.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

You will have to create a property in your ApplicationUser class to reference the documents like this:

```
public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I will try this and accept/upvote/comment to your answer accordingly. :)

Comment: I think `d=>d.UserId` needs to be replaced by `d=>d.User`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a relation but this is optional, may be one or none, you have to put this field as a required if you need to make this relation mandatory:

```
[Required]
public string UserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: But that will throw error at `Mode.IsValid`. I think I am missing something else. Because model.isValid will not alllow further execution. But I wanted see constrained error from DB and still have that field as `not required`. I think there is something else I am missing

Comment: See my `Expected Behavour` edit in the original question. My only doubt is, if I have set up the foreign key correctly. And we know that NULL user ID does not exists in ApplicaitonUser table. Then why EF allows me to set the FK as NULL in the Documents table.

Comment: If the Fk is wired up properly, before saving obvisouly it will check the APpliactionuse table. If it does not find an id named as "NULL" it shold throw exception right?

Comment: let me know if you do not understand my confusion. I will explain again.